# Shift <div> Outside Block

Tags: html, css

I have the following razor view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserCost";
}

<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/products.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<div class="home-main">

    <div class="full-width-div">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="usercost-banner" class="jumbotron" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-row bg-deep-blue">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-title">
                Why UserCost
            </div>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

                    <h2>Costing</h2>
                    <p>
                        Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable 
                        enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton 
                        suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on 
                        chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous. 
                        Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness 
                        favourite in extensive exquisite ye. <br /><br />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                            href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301865">
                            Learn more
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

                    <h2>Groupers</h2>
                    <p>
                        Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable
                        enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton
                        suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on
                        chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous.
                        Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness
                        favourite in extensive exquisite ye. <br /><br />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                            href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">
                            Learn more
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <h2>Consultancy</h2>
                    <p>
                        Situation admitting promotion at or to perceived be. Mr acuteness we as estimable
                        enjoyment up. An held late as felt know. Learn do allow solid to grave. Middleton
                        suspicion age her attention. Chiefly several bed its wishing. Is so moments on
                        chamber pressed to. Doubtful yet way properly answered humanity its desirous.
                        Minuter believe service arrived civilly add all. Acuteness allowance an at eagerness
                        favourite in extensive exquisite ye. <br /><br />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                            href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867">
                            Learn more
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

with products.css as

```
#usercost-banner {
    background-image: url("../Resources/Images/Pngs/Products/usercost_wide_banner3000x800.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
}

.full-width-div {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.full-width-div .container-fluid {
    padding-left: 0rem;
    padding-right: 0rem;
}

sgv {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

rect {
    fill: #0094ff;
}

.section-title {
    font: 600 12px/15px Gotham SSm A,Gotham SSm B,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: -130px;
    margin-bottom: 64px;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #161616;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}

.container-row {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.bg-deep-blue {
    background: #226695;
}

.bottom-row {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

This gives me

[image: Have]

But I want something that looks like

[image: Want]

How can I achieve this with HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advise is to use absolute positioning of the element. You need to modify few thing - wrapper block - in your case .container element should have "position: relative" - this will allow you to "move" section-title inside container. And as you know height of the section-title element you can use margin-top: -50% or -60px to have "overlapping" effect.

```
.container {
        position: relative;
    }

.section-title {
            font: 600 12px/15px Gotham SSm A,Gotham SSm B,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            margin-top: -60px;
            background: #161616;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #fff;
        }
```